# Why do two codes perform differently?

Tags: javascript, html

Why do the following two codes perform differently? There is only one difference between the two ends of the code which part 2 has a setTimeout

```js
// 1
var div = document.querySelector('.move');
div.classList.add('start');
div.classList.add('move-active');
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  div.classList.remove('start');
  div.classList.add('end');
});
div.style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    .move {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .start {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .move-active {
      transition: transform 3s ease;
    }
    
    .end {
      transform: translateX(100px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="move" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
// 2
setTimeout(() => {
  var div = document.querySelector('.move');
  div.classList.add('start');
  div.classList.add('move-active');
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    div.classList.remove('start');
    div.classList.add('end');
  });
  div.style.display = 'block';
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    .move {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .start {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .move-active {
      transition: transform 3s ease;
    }
    
    .end {
      transform: translateX(100px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="move" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

1. In the first part of the code, each browser refresh will have animation effect
2. But in the second part of the code, each browser refresh will have animation effect

Why does setTimeout have different effects on the same code? Isn't setTimeout putting the whole code block in the event loop thread and then executing it in the JS engine thread?

Comment: using `setTimeout(..., 0)` will call the function after every other synchronous action has been completed.

Comment: What are the effects? I don’t understand your list where both things say _“each browser refresh will have animation effect”_.

Comment: I tried running your code snippet. It behaves exactly the same way. What is your question again?

Comment: The “animation effect” is red square moves from left to right

Comment: Note that `setTimeout(fn)` and `setTimeout(fn, 0)` are technically identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and in both cases, most of the time the animation was not there. But sometimes, [when the stars align](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=when%20the%20stars%20align), there was an animation of the Redbox moving from left to right.

I think this is dependent on the [request animation call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and pure luck instead of your usage of `setTimeout`. If the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` function is called on the next repaint after the Redbox has been painted, then the animation will be there otherwise not.

You can, however, make this behavior more reliable using the `setTimeout` function. Below is an example using your code.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    var div = document.querySelector('.move');
    div.classList.add('start');
    div.classList.add('move-active');
    setTimeout(function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        div.classList.remove('start');
        div.classList.add('end');
      });
    }, 0);
    div.style.display = 'block';
}, 0);
```

```css
.move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.start {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.move-active {
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
.end {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="move" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`setTimeout` will delegate the `requestAnimationFrame` function call to the next event loop cycle. At that time, `requestAnimationFrame` will delegate the callback to the next repaint. This should, in most cases, remove the `start` class and add the `end` class to the element after it has been painted resulting in the animation taking place.